# How to extract a specific substring (based on regex) from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a big array of strings:

```
['{{Wanted Value}}', 'true', '{{Wanted Value}}', '{{Wanted Value}} unwanted {{Wanted Value}}', 'false'...]
```

I want to filter the array and extract every `{{Wanted Value}}` substring to a new array. If the item in the array contains 2 or more of these substrings, I want to have each of them as a separate item. So the result of the above array would be:

```
['{{Wanted Value}}', {{Wanted Value}}', {{Wanted Value}}', {{Wanted Value}}']
```

I wrote the regex I want to use but not sure how to write the filter function correctly:

```
match(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/)[0]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach

- `flatMap` is to collect all matched strings
- `filter` is to get rid of empty results

```js
const data =['{{Wanted Value}}', 'true', '{{Wanted Value}}', '{{Wanted Value}} unwanted {{Wanted Value}}', 'false']

const result = data.flatMap(stringData => stringData.match(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g)).filter(stringData => stringData);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which use `reduce` and string `match` function to filter the result

```js
let r = ['{{Wanted Value}}', 'true', '{{Wanted Value}}', '{{Wanted Value}}', 'unwanted','{{Wanted Value}}', 'false'];

const result = r.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  return current.match(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/)? accumulator.concat(current): accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```